# Flip one coin, $Pr\{\text{head}\}=\frac13, Pr\{\text{tail}\} = \frac23$. What are the four possible outcomes and their probabilities after $2$ flips?

Tags: probability

I met the question in my exam:

Flip one coin, the probability of head is $\frac13$, $Pr\{\text{tail}\} = \frac23$. Flip the coin twice, what are the four possible outcomes and their probabilities?

Answer (score 3):

```
Head Head 1/3 * 1/3 = 1/9
Head Tail 1/3 * 2/3 = 2/9
Tail Head 2/3 * 1/3 = 2/9
Tail Tail 2/3 * 2/3 = 4/9
```

By the way, the results of 1st and 2nd flips are [independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29).

Answer (score 2):

```
Head Head: 1/3 * 1/3 = 1/9
Head Tail: 1/3 * 2/3 = 2/9
Tail Head: 2/3 * 1/3 = 2/9
Tail Tail: 2/3 * 2/3 = 4/9
```